Homebrew libraries & CMake on MacOS Sonoma: ld does not find symbols despite correct specified architecture
Problem
I am trying to port a C++ project from Linux to MacOs sonoma with the arm64 architecture.
Configuring is done via CMAKE and the following toolchain

GCC 14 from Homebrew
HDF5 (installed via Homebrew)
Boost program options (installed via Homebrew)

The configuration and compilation step is finished correctly. However, when the project is supposed to be linked together several symbols cannot be resolved by ld and the following error occurs:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
However, when I checked the .dylib files of the homebrew formulae I get the correct architecture:
➜  ~ file /opt/homebrew/lib/libhdf5.dylib 
/opt/homebrew/lib/libhdf5.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
➜  ~ file /opt/homebrew/lib/libboost_program_options.dylib 
/opt/homebrew/lib/libboost_program_options.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64

The CMake project compiles without any errors but it seems that the libraries are not visible to the linker.
Do I have to add something to CMake configuration for this?
Full linker error output
/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-14 -std=c++17 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -g  -g -DNUM_OUT -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/ISHTAR.dir/main.cpp.o -o ISHTAR  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/lib  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.8/lib/libgsl.dylib  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.8/lib/libgslcblas.dylib  /opt/homebrew/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib  /opt/homebrew/lib/libhdf5_cpp.310.0.3.dylib  /opt/homebrew/lib/libhdf5_hl_cpp.310.0.3.dylib  /opt/homebrew/lib/libhdf5_hl.310.0.3.dylib  /opt/homebrew/lib/libhdf5.310.3.0.dylib && :
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "H5::H5File::openFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, unsigned int, H5::FileAccPropList const&)", referenced from:
      test_hdf5_support() in main.cpp.o
  "H5::H5File::H5File(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, unsigned int, H5::FileCreatPropList const&, H5::FileAccPropList const&)", referenced from:
      init_HDF5_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>) in main.cpp.o
      test_hdf5_support() in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::to_internal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&)", referenced from:
      std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> boost::program_options::to_internal<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> const&) in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template[abi:cxx11](boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)", referenced from:
      boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, int) in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> boost::program_options::parse_config_file<char>(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>>&, boost::program_options::options_description const&, bool)", referenced from:
      read_config(int, char**) in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      read_config(int, char**) in main.cpp.o
      read_config(int, char**) in main.cpp.o
      read_config(int, char**) in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::program_options::validate<double, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> const&, double*, long) in main.cpp.o
      void boost::program_options::validate<int, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> const&, int*, long) in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, int)", referenced from:
      boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, int) in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::arg[abi:cxx11]", referenced from:
      boost::program_options::typed_value<bool, char>::name[abi:cxx11]() const in main.cpp.o
      boost::program_options::typed_value<double, char>::name[abi:cxx11]() const in main.cpp.o
      boost::program_options::typed_value<int, char>::name[abi:cxx11]() const in main.cpp.o
      boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, char>::name() const in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> const&)", referenced from:
      boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*) in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>*, int)", referenced from:
      boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> const&) const in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> const&, bool*, int)", referenced from:
      boost::program_options::typed_value<bool, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> const&) const in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)", referenced from:
      read_config(int, char**) in main.cpp.o
  "H5::H5Location::createGroup(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      add_group(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>) in main.cpp.o
  "H5::H5Location::openDataSet(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, H5::DSetAccPropList const&) const", referenced from:
      extend_group_with_vector_int(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>) in main.cpp.o
      update_group_with_vector_double(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>) in main.cpp.o
      extend_group_with_vector_double(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>) in main.cpp.o
      read_vector_int(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>) in main.cpp.o
      read_vector_double(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>) in main.cpp.o
      test_hdf5_support() in main.cpp.o
  "H5::H5Location::createDataSet(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&, H5::DataType const&, H5::DataSpace const&, H5::DSetCreatPropList const&, H5::DSetAccPropList const&, H5::LinkCreatPropList const&) const", referenced from:
      add_group_with_vector_double(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>) in main.cpp.o
      add_group_with_vector_int(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>) in main.cpp.o
      test_hdf5_support() in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for boost::program_options::invalid_option_value in main.cpp.o
      vtable for boost::program_options::validation_error in main.cpp.o
      vtable for boost::wrapexcept<boost::program_options::validation_error> in main.cpp.o
      vtable for boost::wrapexcept<boost::program_options::invalid_option_value> in main.cpp.o
  "boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>>> const&, bool) const", referenced from:
      vtable for boost::program_options::typed_value<bool, char> in main.cpp.o
      vtable for boost::program_options::typed_value<double, char> in main.cpp.o
      vtable for boost::program_options::typed_value<int, char> in main.cpp.o
      vtable for boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, char> in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64


It seems like the affected libraries are not installed under the correct architecture so I tried already to see if the installed libraries are installed within the correct architecture and resetting the CMake project.
However, all files were installed in the arm64 architecture.
The CMake file works correctly on Linux x86_64.

try building with clang

Thank you! I wanted to use GCC as a compiler since the project also depends on OpenMP and Apple Clang is not supporting OpenMP natively. However I found a workaround here:
https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/
With both these work-arounds I was able to compile the project.
